# how to set this code in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, css

I use this code in wordpress for showing jquery, but it doesn't show.

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js" type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
```